# Writing JUnit tests for Toasts in an Android app

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, error-handling, junit

I often use `Toast.makeText().show()` to display messages to the user of my Android app. These can be instructions what to do next or error messages. As part of my JUnit tests, I would like to include assertions that these messages appear when expected. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I can't answer your question but I have to comment about using `Toast` for instructions or reporting error messages. A `Toast` is meant to be short-lived and it's easy for a user to miss this type of message. In other words, don't use `Toast` for anything which is crucial to the UX - display a dialog or a notification instead....something permanent in case the user is distracted and doesn't see your `Toast` messages.

Comment: @Squonk That's a good point. I will certainly consider changing my UI to use something other than `Toast`s. I suspect I will encounter similar issues when trying to write tests.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405080/how-to-test-for-the-appearance-of-a-toast-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since originally asking this question, I have found the following solution which works well for me:

```
public static void waitForToast(Solo solo, String message) {
    Assert.assertTrue(solo.waitForDialogToOpen(TIME_OUT));
    Assert.assertTrue(solo.searchText(message));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do it by using **Robotium** framework, and calling this immediately after the toast is shown:

```
     TextView toastTextView = solo.getText(0);
     if(toastTextView != null){
         String toastText = toastTextView.getText().toString();
         assertEquals(toastText, "Your expected text here");
     }
     //wait for Toast to close
     solo.waitForDialogToClose(5000);
```

Comment: Robotium is on my long list of technologies to learn. Thanks for the answer to my question and reminding me to download and take a look at this testing framework.