# Logging value of a variable in MonkeyTalk IDE Javascript file

Tags: javascript, android, ios, bdd, monkeytalk

I'm using MonkeyTalk IDE Beta2 for testing iPad application. I exported the javascript from the MonkeyTalk IDE and got a new .js file. I am storing the Boolean value of a `Verify` command in a `var` and want to see what is its value, and accordingly do custom logic. I tried `document.write`, `console.log` and `alert` used in javascript but got an error that they are not defined. Please help me with this.

Also, is it possible to output the result of a test as XML (as in FoneMonkey) or as an Excel spreadsheet or something like that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not*, but to date there is no way direct way to cause MonkeyTalk to log messages to the console. What you can do, however, is abuse a command like `verifyNot` which will result in a log message. In a MonkeyTalk .mt this would be done like:

```
View * VerifyNot Message
```

I created the following helper script called `log.js` for this purpose. Timestamps are automatically added by Eclipse, but not elsewhere so I have prepended the time.

```
load("libs/Executor.js");

function getTimeStamp() {
    var now = new Date();
    return now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
}

EXECUTOR.defineScript("Log", function(msg) {
    this.app.view().verifyNot(getTimeStamp() + ": " + msg);
});
```

Finally, you don't need the executor boilerplate (only the verifyNot line), but we use that with [scripts by Doba](https://www.gorillalogic.com/content/monkeytalk-hacking-wanna-share-my-js-stuffs) in order to be able to organize files in different directories (Doba.js renamed to Executor.js) -- another feature not available out of the box.

* It's almost like GorillaLogic doesn't want you to be able to resolve your own problems. ;)

Comment: And to address your second question, I don't have any knowledge of a capability like that either.