# Monkeytalk:I am not able to automate the text area for which AutoCompleteTextView has been used

Tags: android, automation

I want to automate android application using MonkeyTalk IDE.
I am not able to automate the text area for which AutoCompleteTextView has been used.
Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get this working either, nor do the views for the rows show up on the component tree.

Monkeytalk has trouble with many widgets including popups and dialogs, so this doesn't surprise me.  For example, [we had to rotate 90 degrees](http://www.gorillalogic.com/content/unable-record-specific-menu-button-press) in order to be able to press a pop-up menu option.  On the other hand it supposedly supports spinners.

Comment: John Can you suggest me any other android Automation tool

Comment: @AmbeshThakur check out my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759626/how-do-you-test-an-android-application-across-multiple-activities/14569759#14569759