# ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 cannot setup new test after activity transition

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-activity, android-instrumentation

I am trying to test a button that start a new activity using only ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 without Robotium, and it's working fine, but when I try to run the next test case, it's not able to start.

Following what was explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759626/how-do-you-test-an-android-application-across-multiple-activities), I was able to continue the test in the next activity and keep performing clicks, but I would like to separate the tests in different functions.

I tried to start a new activity on setup using the following code but it didn't work, I also tried to do the same thing on each function but it didn't work too.

```
    Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();      
    Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor monitor = instrumentation.addMonitor(AuthenticateActivity.class.getName(), null, false);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setClassName(instrumentation.getTargetContext(), AuthenticateActivity.class.getName());
    instrumentation.startActivitySync(intent);
    Activity currentActivity = instrumentation.waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, 5);
```

How can I start a new activity and keep running the next test functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

After some debugs I noticed that the second test was hanging on the startActivitySync() method when I was calling getActivity(), it was happening because I was not finishing the previous started Activity. To finish it, I did the following:

```
    Button button = testActivity.findViewById(R.id.button);
    //add the monitor before starting the new activity
    Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor monitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(StartedActivity.class.getName(), null, false);

    //Clicking this button will open the new Activity
    TouchUtils.clickView(this, button);
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();

    //get the started Activity
    StartedActivity startedActivity = (StartedActivity)instrumentation.waitForMonitor(monitor);
    //finishing the started activity solved the problem
    startedActivity.finish();
```